# Where are the main clothes shopping areas in London?

Tags: london, shopping

My wife and I are visiting London soon and we would like to find the best clothing stores - we want to visit the popular big shops but we’d also like to visit some local independent shops.

I would also like to find outlet stores where I can buy good stuff in a good price.

Comment: Should (open air) markets be included?

Comment: All of London is filled with shops.

Comment: @Calchas not particularly useful though. There are shops but not large groups of "the best stores" all over London.

Comment: @Muzer Alright I was a bit sardonic. Popular big shops, local independents, and outlet stores ... that covers a lot of bases, and there can't be many places within Zone 1 where you wouldn't be in walking distance of at least one of those. Flagging as too broad.

Comment: What sort of shopping are you interested in - clothes, electronics, books, something else; famous brands or unique things; cheap, mid-market, exclusive? London doesn't really have any one central shopping district, rather, lots of different areas with focuses on different things and different characters and price levels

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I'm looking for clothing shops.

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to say what's the "best" as different places suit different needs.

Oxford Street (and it's surrounding roads) and Regent Street are quite famous for shopping and likely to find what you like.

Apart from that, there are 3 shopping centers which you can visit

- Westfield (Shepherds Bush)
- Westfield (Stratford)
- Bluewater

All the 3 shopping centers are easily accessible by public transport and have decent parking facilities as well.

Comment: Carnaby Street is near the Oxford Street / Regent Street junction and would tick the "independent fashion shops" box, [it's been famous for that since the 1960s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnaby_Street), while Oxford Street and Regent Street would tick the "popular big shops" box (be warned that Oxford St is hellishly busy, locals try hard to avoid it, but it has almost all the big 'high street' clothes shops in one place - and many tourists seem to like how busy it is?)

Answer (score -1):

According to [VisitLondon.com](http://www.visitlondon.com/things-to-do/shopping/top-shopping-destinations#hceoZmudYCvb4B5h.97), it lists the following as some of "the best shops in London for your ultimate London shopping experience":

- Oxford Street
- Regent Street and Jermyn Street
- Bond Street and Mayfair
- Westfield
- Carnaby Street
- Covent Garden
- King's Road
- Knightsbridge
- Savile Row
- Camden
- Notting Hill
- Spitalfields
- Canary Wharf

Comment: This answer could benefit with some detail about what sort of shops you can find in different places. e.g. Oxford Street for flagship stores of chain retailers, Spitalfields for independent craft stalls.